# Substituting with sed ignores whitespace

Tags: bash, sed, morse-code

Let's say I have a file named `m1.txt`, whose contents (`- . ... - / -. --- / .----`)  I want to decode from Morse to text. Here's what I have written:

```
sed -i 's/.- /A/g' m1.txt
sed -i 's/-... /B/g' m1.txt
sed -i 's/-.-. /C/g' m1.txt
```

and so on, including numbers, and later on:

```
sed -i 's:/ : :g' m1.txt
cat m1.txt
```

in order to clear the separating slash and output the message.

The expected output is `TEST NO 1`, however the program outputs `D...AE-ED.--A` instead, ignoring any whitespaces and returning a wrong message. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You're missing the fact that `.` is a metacharacter in regular expressions. Basically, `.` matches *any* character. If you want to match a literal `.` character, you need to escape it: `sed -i 's/-\.\.\. /B/g' m1.txt`

Comment: Google for morse code generator using bash.

Comment: there are also interactions because you remove the spaces.  so the order of letter application is going to matter, unless you preserve the spaces until the end

Comment: and you won't match that last 1 unless you leave a space after it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to escape `.`, since it will match any character
2. You need to consider interactions, since `.` (E) will match a single dot, it will also match the end of (N) `-.` unless you consider them in the right order or preserve the separators (on both the left and right).

(1) is obvious to solve, simply escape the `.`. 
For (2), we can first map the beginning and end of the line to spaces (so that we have separators consistently on the left and right, and then we preserve the separators on output (to avoid interactions).  Then, in the second to last line, clean up the spaces.  Then, in the final line, map your slashes to the word break spaces which are the only spaces you want in your output.

I didn't do the whole alphabet for you, just enough for you to see the idea.

Here's a working solution:

```
$ cat m1.txt 
- . ... - / -. --- / .----
$ cat morse.sed 
s/^/ /
s/$/ /
s/ - / T /g
s/ \. / E /g
s/ \.\.\. / S /g
s/ -\.\ / N /g
s/ --- / O /g
s/ \.---- / 1 /g
s/[ ]\+//g
s:/: :g
$ cat m1.txt | sed -f morse.sed 
TEST NO 1
```

Note: this answer was revised because I didn't at first realize that the `(` and `)` were not part of the input.  Also, @Bach Lien's idea to map the anchors to spaces in the first lines is a great one, it makes things a lot cleaner, so I've incorporated that idea.

Comment: So, do I add `[) ]` in all lines, or just the first and last ones?

Comment: Yes, you need to match either the paran `(` or a space ` ` on both the left and right side of the sequence in order to make the morse code unambiguous (otherwise, note that E or T appears inside other sequences).  The paran is because you seem to have parans on the left and right side of the message, if you had something other delmiter, you'd put that, or if you had no delimiters, you might use the anchors `^` and `$`.  I edited the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Okay, the only issue right now is adding a space at the beginning of the text, so that the first character can be translated properly. In the case of the example text, I get `-EST NO 1`, with `T` not being properly modified. I've looked up various solutions, and even made up some, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: So, if your input has the `(` at the beginning of the line, you should be fine with `s/[( ]-[) ]/ T /g`.  If your input does not have `(` on the beginning of the line, then could you clarify your question to show what your input actually looks like?

Comment: So, assuming the user does not include `(` or a space on the beginning of the line, the input is exactly the same as the example text, `- . ... - / -. --- / .----`, and this is where the problem in my last comment emerges.

Comment: Oh, I see now that your parans are actually outside of your input.  I'm sorry, I'll revise the answer now.  Standby.

Answer (score 3):

Morse table (morse-to-char mapping):

```
$ cat morse-table.txt 
## this is table of char-to-morse-code mapping
## taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code
## dated: 2018 01 23

## characters
A .-
B -...
C -.-.
D -..
E .
F ..-.
G --.
H ....
I ..
J .---
K -.-
L .-..
M --
N -.
O ---
P .--.
Q --.-
R .-.
S ...
T -
U ..-
V ...-
W .--
X -..-
Y -.--
Z --..

## numbers
1 .----
2 ..---
3 ...--
4 ....-
5 .....
6 -....
7 --...
8 ---..
9 ----.
0 -----

## special symbols
## in fact, there is no
## such symbols in traditional morse codes
## this part is fake, just for testing
. .......
\ -------
/ -.-.-.-
? --.--.-
[ .--.--.
] --..--.
```

Program to convert Morse table to `sed` script:

```
$ cat make-m2t.sh 
#!/bin/bash

t=morse-table.txt                     # morse table
s=m2t                                 # sed script

s1='                                  # s1 = pre-processing
s:\s+:  :g                            # space-gap to TWO space-chars
s:^: :                                # add a space at line beginning
s:$: :                                # add a space at line end
s:/: \n :g                            # change all slash to " \n "
'
s2='                                  # s2 = morse-table to sed-script
s:\s+: :g                             # space-gap to space-char
s:##.*$::                             # remove all comments
s:^ *::                               # remove all leading spaces
s: *$::                               # remove all trailing spaces
/^[^ ] [\.-]+$/!d                     # ignore all invalid lines
s:\.:\\.:g                            # add back-slash for dot (escape for dot)
s:^\\\. :\. :                         # but not for the char-dot
s:^\\ :\\\\ :                         # add b-slash for b-slash (escape for b-slash)
s:^\/ :\\\/ :                         # add b-slash for slash (escape for slash)
s:^([^ ]+) +([^ ]+).*$:s/ \2 / \1 /g: # morse-map to sed-subsitution
'
s3='                                  # s3 = post-processing
s: ::g                                # remove all spaces
s:\n: :g                              # convert \n to space
'
                                      # now, make the sed script
echo '#!/usr/bin/sed -Ef'      >"$s"  # shebang
sed -E 's:\s*#.*$::' <<<"$s1" >>"$s"  # remove comments from s1
sed -E "$s2" "$t"             >>"$s"  # convert morse to chars
sed -E 's:\s*#.*$::' <<<"$s3" >>"$s"  # remove comments from s3
sed -i -E '/^\s*$/d'            "$s"  # remove all blank lines
chmod +x                        "$s"  # make it executable
```

Test:

```
$ ./make-m2t.sh
$ echo '- . ... -/-. ---/.----' | ./m2t
TEST NO 1
$ echo '.--.--. .... . .-.. .-.. --- --..--./....... --.--.-' | ./m2t
[HELLO] .?
$ cat m1.txt 
- . ... - / -. --- / .----
$ ./m2t m1.txt 
TEST NO 1
$ cat m2t
#!/usr/bin/sed -Ef
s:\s+:  :g
s:^: :
s:$: :
s:/: \n :g
s/ \.- / A /g
s/ -\.\.\. / B /g
s/ -\.-\. / C /g
s/ -\.\. / D /g
s/ \. / E /g
s/ \.\.-\. / F /g
s/ --\. / G /g
s/ \.\.\.\. / H /g
s/ \.\. / I /g
s/ \.--- / J /g
s/ -\.- / K /g
s/ \.-\.\. / L /g
s/ -- / M /g
s/ -\. / N /g
s/ --- / O /g
s/ \.--\. / P /g
s/ --\.- / Q /g
s/ \.-\. / R /g
s/ \.\.\. / S /g
s/ - / T /g
s/ \.\.- / U /g
s/ \.\.\.- / V /g
s/ \.-- / W /g
s/ -\.\.- / X /g
s/ -\.-- / Y /g
s/ --\.\. / Z /g
s/ \.---- / 1 /g
s/ \.\.--- / 2 /g
s/ \.\.\.-- / 3 /g
s/ \.\.\.\.- / 4 /g
s/ \.\.\.\.\. / 5 /g
s/ -\.\.\.\. / 6 /g
s/ --\.\.\. / 7 /g
s/ ---\.\. / 8 /g
s/ ----\. / 9 /g
s/ ----- / 0 /g
s/ \.\.\.\.\.\.\. / . /g
s/ ------- / \\ /g
s/ -\.-\.-\.- / \/ /g
s/ --\.--\.- / ? /g
s/ \.--\.--\. / [ /g
s/ --\.\.--\. / ] /g
s: ::g
s:\n: :g
```

---

**Note:**

1. User only need to define the morse-table.txt, to map morse codes to characters
2. Based on morse-table, `bash` program would generate `sed` script to convert morse codes to text
3. The `sed` script is based on the solution of @JawguyChooser.
4. Because we use space `' '` as "delimiter" of Morse block, so, when pre-processing we must convert all space gap to TWO space-characters; otherwise error will occur for words like `'HELLO'` (double `L`)